# PowerMockito Static

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to mock Static methods using PowerMockito. It works fine when I try To mock only one Class. For instance **Class1.*staticMethod()***. But my tested class uses other static method from other class **Class2.*staticMethod()***.

So my question is: How to mock two different static methods from different classes, in the same test using PowerMockito?

I can not use `mockito-inline` dependency, so it should be done only with PowerMockito.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply provide two static mocks you can control the behavior of each method.

I usually do something like this in Mockito:

```
protected static MockedStatic<Class1> CLASS1_MOCK= Mockito.mockStatic(Class1.class);
CLASS1_MOCK.when(Class1::staticMethod).thenReturn(testValue1);

protected static MockedStatic<Class2> CLASS2_MOCK = Mockito.mockStatic(Class2.class);
CLASS2_MOCK.when(Class2::staticMethod).thenReturn(testValue2);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I can not use MockedStatic class because it requires to add new Maven depedencies and it is not part of PowerMockito.